# Should POST request return 404 if reference to other entity fails?

Tags: rest

I'm building an API which operates on a noun `Foo`. When a caller creates an instance of `Foo` with a POST request, they are required to provide an ID to a second noun, `Bar`. If the ID they provided is of the right type but there is no `Bar` with that ID, is 404 the right response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response code 400 or 403 for POST Restful APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912305/response-code-400-or-403-for-post-restful-apis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: No. Your API should be "user-friendly" meaning, if there is an error it should return it in a way that the user can figure out what the problem was. Returning 404 is like saying that the service was not found which is not true. The response should be [*403*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) - cause it could be that the resource with the ID that the client tries to approach belong to a different client!

In addition, the response should contain an error message/code (in the body) which can be parsed and analyzed by the client.

Comment: 400 feels like an odd choice if the request was syntactically correct: The caller gave the right type for `id` but the value doesn't resolve properly. Is 422/Unprocessable Entity accepted enough for use?

Comment: @ehdv 422 means semantic errors. Looks like 403 will be a better fit.

Comment: In your question you state: "If the ID they provided is of the right type but there is no Bar...".  That sounds like a bad request.  The client is referring to a server entity that does not exist.

Comment: One could make a case for returning a 500 response.  If the client believes that the Bar reference is valid, then the server's failure to process this request could be viewed as exceptional.  This could happen for example if the reference is valid, but the a different client deletes it.  In this scenario, the first client is not doing anything wrong.

Comment: One could make a case for a 500 response being appropriate only if the processing is due to a misconfiguration (i.e., an internal server error) on the server itself, through no fault of the client. If the client is sending bad data, that necessitates a response code in the 400 family.

Comment: Furthermore, a 401 response means something incredibly specific in HTTP land. It should always be accompanied by a WWW-Authenticate response header, indicating to the client needs to provide the requested credentials for the specified realm using HTTP Basic or Digest. If that's not this situation, do *not* use a 401.

Comment: @JonathanW Agreed, I think too that 403 would be more appropriate.

Comment: How about a [409 Conflict](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) response? That way you could specify "x entity was not found".

Comment: @ChristianPotdevin from the link you provided: "This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request". If the ID of Bar is not found, we could use 409 only in case we expect the user to fix the request and re-send it by providing an ID to a different Bar entity. I suspect that the chances of that happening are not great.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I believe the important part of that line of text is: "the user **might** be able to resolve the conflict". From what I understand the purpose is to inform the user why there is a conflict in the internal state of the resource and let the user decide if he/she wants to correct the request by finding the correct id for the Bar or leave it be.

Comment: @ChristianPotdevin the OP did not imply that a user will be able to resolve the conflict, or even if there's a "user" on the other end (this is an API call, it could be triggered by automation). If the scenario is such that the call is triggered by a user and there's an option to recover by providing a different `Bar` ID, then you're correct and 409 will be more suitable. Keep in mind that this is correct only if these two assumptions turn to be true!

Answer (score 18):

I think it depends on whether the ID is in the URL or not. The URL is the address for a resource, if the ID is in the URL and no item with this ID exists, or you don't provide it at all, then the URL is invalid, so no resource could be found, so that's a 404.

However, if the ID is **not** in the URL but in the data from the POST request, and the URL is a valid address to a resource, then a 400 Bad Request should be returned.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest using HTTP 400 (Bad Request).

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1.  One could interpret 400 as a generic indication that the client did not form the request correctly.

One could also make a case for returning a 500 response.  If the client believes that the Bar reference is valid, then the server's failure to process this request could be viewed as exceptional.  This could happen for example if the reference is valid, but the a different client deletes it.  In this scenario, the first client is not doing anything wrong.

Comment: One could make a case for a 500 response being appropriate only if the processing is due to a misconfiguration (i.e., an internal server error) on the server itself, through no fault of the client. If the client is sending bad data, that necessitates a response code in the 400 family.

Comment: The current definition of the 400 response (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) states it should be used when the request cannot be processed due to a "client error". Client sending an invalid reference clearly falls under that category.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit grey area.

Although the **500** response code looks like a good fit because of its broader context, the **404** response code could also be considered.

The reason that I am not sure about the **404** code is the main purpose of your request. The request is sent to create a new resource. It is not for retrieving an existing resource. Though the root cause is the "Not Found" resource, the intention of the request is for a new entity. Getting the **404** response code might cause ambiguity for the client. Therefore, the **500** with a good explanation looks like a better option.

I can clearly state that the **400** response code **is not convenient** for this case because there is nothing wrong with the request syntax.

The following definitions from [MDN Web Docs - HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) might help to make a decision.

**400 Bad Request:**

> The server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.

**404 Not Found:**

> The server can not find the requested resource. In the browser, this
> means the URL is not recognized. In an API, this can also mean that
> the endpoint is valid but the resource itself does not exist. Servers
> may also send this response instead of 403 to hide the existence of a
> resource from an unauthorized client. This response code is probably
> the most famous one due to its frequent occurrence on the web.

**500 Internal Server Error:**

> The server has encountered a situation it doesn't know how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

- 4xx is entitled "Client Error" in the standard
- 5xx is entitled "Server Error"

If the server is 100% sure that the reference to Bar *could not be correct* (that id is totally invalid format or couldn't have existed) then that's a straight up 400 Bad Request.

If the server allowed someone to delete that Bar where such deletion should not be allowed (Foo should go down with it) then that's a 500 Internal Server Error.

Here the client is *creating* a Foo with a dangling reference to a Bar (since it's a POST, if it were updating a Foo it would be a PUT).  The client got a reference to the referenced Bar somehow and can presumably find an appropriate existing Bar if it tried again.  In that case, the server returns 409 Conflict to signal that the request, while valid, is in conflict with the state of the server and needs to be dropped or reconstructed so that it is consistent with the state of the server.  The 409 response should specify that the problem is that the referenced Bar does not exist.