# Response code 400 or 403 for POST Restful APIs

Tags: web-services, rest

I am designing a POST Restful API, where I have a situation that I have to authorize a user based upon one of the element provided in the request body.
For eg.

```
{
division : "1",
name : "MyName",
address:{
no : 123,
street : "abc",
pincode : 222111
}
....
}
```

So the user making POST request should be authorized to work on division 1. I cannot authorize the user without getting request body.

Also to validate some of the attributes I have to make heavy DB calls in the DB , for eg, to check the above address has a valid value of pincode.

So My question is how should I return the error codes to the user -

1. [EDIT]If division is not valid(something that doesnt exist in system) in the request - 400 or 403 ?
2. If division is provided, but user is not authorized and pincode is invalid - 400 for invalid pincode or 403 ?
3. What should be the error code if pincode is mandatory attribute and is not provided in the request. Should I first check 403 and then 400 or reverse ?

Basically which error code to proceed the other ?

Also is it okay to do something like :

```
400 – request is bad, syntactically (division/pincode or other mandatory values not provided)
403 – authorize user
400 – request is bad, data specific validation (heavier operation, requiring to hit DB)
```

[EDIT] we preferred not to use 422 error code

Comment: Please, don't rely on the user to tell you what they're authorised for! POST requests are very easy to view and edit; it's trivial for someone to just tell you they're allowed to do whatever they want. The user should identify themselves, and *you* tell *them* what they're allowed to do.

Comment: `${personalDeity}` ! Forgive me, but the little I know about your application shows that you don't have the slightest clue when it comes to security. ***Please*** do not implement the authorization and authentication routines yourself. Given the knowledge you show, you'll fail miserably. Use a proven framework like [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) or [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should POST request return 404 if reference to other entity fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250409/should-post-request-return-404-if-reference-to-other-entity-fails)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When in doubt, just take a look at the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

---

> 403 Forbidden
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

*If division is not provided in the request - 400 or 403?*

I don't think either apply. The syntax -although it's missing some data- is **not** malformed.
Also 403 seems incorrect because of reasons mentioned above in the quote: *authorization will not help* etc.

How about [422 Unprocessable Entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)?

> 422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
>
> The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to
>   semantic errors.

That is what I usually use in situations like this.

*If division is provided, but user is not authorized and pincode is invalid - 400 for invalid pincode or 403?*

Again, I don't think either 400 or 403 make a good case here. Specifically for this situation, 401 exists

> 401 Unauthorized
>
> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but **specifically for use when authentication
>   is required and has failed or has not yet been provided**. The response
>   must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication
>   and Digest access authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention one thing in my question that we preferred not to use 422 error code. What should be my error code if pincode is mandatory attribute and is not provided in the request. Should I first check 403 and then 400 or reverse ?

Comment: One more- How about if division is invalid in the request body

Comment: I think 403 does not apply for any of your cases.  If you cannot or may not use 422, you can always fall back on 400 as sort of general case, but 422 is bettrt

Comment: 401 is somewhat different for 403, So , in my case user is authorized but forbidden on the provided division. I should ask - Should I validate the request body first and then do the authorization part, or first just check the division and then do the authorization and then do rest of body validations ?

Comment: @VineetSingla authorize first. If the user isn't authorized, there is no need to process the rest of the request

Comment: How about the division attribute then ? If that attribute has invalid value, should I throw user 400 or 403. If I throw 400 , then It will be ambigous, because I am first throwing 400 , then 403 and then again 400

Comment: @VineetSingla 1) check division, if number is invalid return 400. If number is valid then 2) check authorization, if auth is invalid return 401. if auth is valid then 3) proceed with the rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76447/discussion-between-vineet-singla-and-tim-castelijns).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the right track. Assuming that every request is being authenticated via (http authorization header)

1. Returning 400, on missing data is OK, and furthermore you can add error response body explaining what was the reason for the Client request not being accepted (in this case the missing division).
2. Returning 403, is OK if the client making the request is not authorized to interact with the resource (in this case the division).
3. You must validate first if the Client is authorized to interact with the resource, so 403 must be sent first, and if a required field is missing you can treat it as a 400 (with a proper explanation).

In case the Client is not authenticated, the correct response should be 401, but like I said before, 1) and 2) in my response are assuming that the Clients are authenticated against the server.

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: Done, it's in the response now.

Comment: One more- How about if division is invalid in the request body ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are wrong on the 2nd one. 403 is not about being authorized or not. You simply cannot access it

Comment: @VineetSingla The will be a 400, since the request it's malformed and therefore cannot be processed by the server, again let the client know what field is wrong so they have more information about it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403, especially check this: `A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:

Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
The operation is forbidden to all users. Repeating the request with authentication would serve no purpose.` In this case the first condition is the one that applie.

Comment: I did and it agrees with me

Comment: @jbarrueta If you can reword this then `if the client making the request is not authorized` in your 2nd I will remove the  downvote

Comment: Should I validate the request body first and then do the authorization part, or first just check the division and then do the authorization and then do rest of body validations ?

Comment: @VineetSingla, sound like you want to check the division first, then authorize and just then validate the rest of the request. That way you can throw proper errors so the clients know how to fix their request.

Comment: 403 is Forbidden. It is plain english.